# Help with question on Big $O$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose $f(x)$ is a function that satisfies $f(x) = O(1)$ (big oh of $1$)? Is it possible that $e^{f(x)}  = O(1)$?

I think I've figured out the first part of the answer.

We know $(f(x)/g(x)) \leq c$ for all $n \geq k$,

where $f(x) = f(x)$ and $g(x) = 1$

$(f(x)/g(x)) = (f(x)/1) \leq c$ (some constant $c$) for all $n \geq k$
(Assume $k = 1$)

$(f(x)/g(x)) \leq c*1$ for all $n \geq 1$

So $f(x)$ is indeed part of $o(1)$

Assume the top is correct

Is it possible that $e^{f(x)}  = O(1)$ (big oh of $1$)

$(f(x)/g(x)) \leq c$ 
Assume $f(x) = 1$
$(e^1)/1 \leq c$  for all $n \geq k$

$e$ (Euler constant) $\leq c$  for all $n \geq k$

Assume $k = 1$

$e$ (Euler constant) $\leq c$  for all $n \geq 1$

$e \leq c*1$ for all $n \geq 1$

Does this prove that  $e^{f(x)}  = O(1)$? Is my approach correct?

Comment: [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) references for typing maths on the site, mostly it's about surrounding mathy objects with dollar signs. Command like \frac, \ge, \le are useful. As you edit your post, try to think through stuff like what do you mean by $n$ in your current writing. what is provided to you and what do you have to show.

Comment: Please format the question properly as @SiongThyeGoh explains.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = O(1)$
means that 
there is a constant $a$
such that
$|f(x)| < a$.

$e^{f(x)} = O(1)$
means that 
there is a constant $b$
such that
$|e^{f(x)}| < b$.

Since
$|e^{f(x)}| < e^a$,
$e^{f(x)} = O(1)$
with constant
$b = e^a$.